# Importing existing heroku project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, heroku, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse to work with heroku. Well while importing apps to eclispe am getting this error always "Associate your SSH key to your Heroku account by going to Preferences". Well even tried to create a new ssh key and added the same to heroku account. But am still getting this error againa nd again. Any idea?

Comment: Same thing for me. Any solution?